# How do I TRY Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualization, macosx

Well, I've heard that Ubuntu is a Great Operating System, and I'd LOVE to try it. I have a MacBook, and don't want to replace OS X Mountain Lion. How do try Ubuntu without uninstalling OS X?

Comment: First, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Second, do you want to TRY it, or permanently install it alongside OS X? If you just want to try it, I'd recommend VirtualBox. https://www.virtualbox.org/ Otherwise, I could tell you how to install it next to OS X using rEFIt so you can choose when you start the computer. I currently have Ubuntu 12.10 running alongside OS X on my MacBook Pro - it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VirtualBox for OSX

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

This will let you run a copy of Ubuntu in a window on your Mac.  You could also shrink your OSX partition and use ReFit, but if this is your first time with Ubuntu and you want to just try it, I would stick with VirtualBox (or, if you have it, VMWare)

Instructions for shrinking your OSX disk space to make room for Ubuntu and doing a dual boot install are here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

But note the comment about using this on recent macs and the latest Ubuntu